# Center buttons in middle of image

Tags: html, css

I try to make buttons that will be in the middle of the picture, but the problem is that either those buttons are in the middle of the page or under the picture. Any suggestions how to fix it and what I do wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/m5g16vt7/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

imageSlide-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: pink;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="imageSlide-container">
  <img class="imageSlide" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width: 100%">

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlide-button(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlide-button(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you forgot to add a dot to the class .imageSlide-container.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check below snippet

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}
   body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
            
        .imageSlide-container {
          max-width: 1000px;
          position: relative;
          margin: auto;
            }
            
   .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: pink;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        transform: translateY(-50%;)
   }
   .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
   }
   .prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)
   }
            @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
     .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
     }
```

```html
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="imageSlide-container">
   <img class="imageSlide" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width: 100%">

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlide-button(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlide-button(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

You forgot  to add `.` before class name  `imageSlide-container` in css
and you need to add `transform: translateY(-50%;)` and `top:50%` to adjust arrows vertically centered.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a dot in the css:

```
.imageSlide-container {
     max-width: 1000px;
     position: relative;
     margin: auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add dot(.) infront of **imageSlide-container**

```
.imageSlide-container {
            max-width: 1000px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. However if you want to place buttons center of the image just adjust your top margin and if left or right just change the *text-align* property.

```css
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      * {box-sizing:border-box}
   body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
            
            imageSlide-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
            }
       .buttons{
         text-align: center;
        margin-top: -45px;
       }  
   .prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
        top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    color: pink;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
   }
   .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
   }
   .prev:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)
   }
            @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
     .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
     }
```

```html
<div class="imageSlide-container">
   <img class="imageSlide" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width: 100%">

      <div class="buttons">
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlide-button(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlide-button(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
</div>
```